Installation problems for SceneBuilder for JavaFX on Ubuntu
I am not able to install the .deb package of SceneBuilder for JavaFX on Ubuntu.
Environment______________________________________
Ubuntu: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS; 
Java:
    java version "23.0.1" 2024-10-15
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 23.0.1+11-39)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0.1+11-39, mixed mode, sharing)
JavaFX: 23.0.1
SceneBuilder: 23.0.1

When I run the below command I get error
sudo dpkg -i SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb
Error______________________________
Selecting previously unselected package scenebuilder.
(Reading database ... 225792 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack SceneBuilder-23.0.1.deb ...
Unpacking scenebuilder (23.0.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of scenebuilder:
 scenebuilder depends on libffi7; however:
  Package libffi7 is not installed.
 scenebuilder depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0; however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 scenebuilder depends on libpcre3; however:
  Package libpcre3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package scenebuilder (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 scenebuilder

After searching on internet I ran the below command which uninstalled the package.
sudo apt-get install -f
Output_______________________________________
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  scenebuilder
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 194 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 225980 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing scenebuilder (23.0.1) ...

I ran this command next
sudo apt-get purge
Output________________________________
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.

Then the command
sudo apt-get clean (there was no output for this command and got back the prompt)
sudo apt-get check
Output________________________________
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

Then the command
sudo dpkg --configure -a (there was no output for this command and got back the prompt)
I tried installing again with same result.
What am I doing wrong?

There is an open bug related to installation of libffi7 (and therefore libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 dependency) for scenebuilder version > 23.0. See
https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/issues/796
However, you should be able to install dependency libpcre3:
sudo apt install libpcre3
